# Create new columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. My goal is to create 2 new columns based on the conditions as listed below.

id     a       b       c        new col1       new col2
1     99      0.1      5
2     35      0.4      6
3     60      0.9      3
4     99      0.04     0

[image]

```
if(df['a'] > 50 & df['b'] >= 0.04 and df['c'] ==0):
    df['nc1'] = 'message1'
    df['nc2'] = 'message2'
elif(df['a'] >= 50 & df['b'] < 0.04 and df['c'] > 0):
    df['nc1'] = 'message3'
    df['nc2'] = 'message4'
else:
    df['nc1'] = null
    df['nc2'] = null
```

When I try giving only 1 condition in the if else structure it works , but the code fails when I try to add more conditions with error 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'

I tried modifying the code adding conditions and then using np.where to create the new columns, but that I dont think is the right approach to solve it.

Can anyone please help in resolving this issue? This is something I am trying to solve for work, so could not paste the actual code snippet, but this gives the overall idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your data as text instead of [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: try this (similar thing for col2): df['new col1'] = np.where((df['a'] > 50) & (df['b'] >= 0.04) & (df['c'] == 0), 'message1',
                          np.where((df['a'] >= 50) & (df['b'] < 0.04) & (df['c'] > 0), 'message3', np.nan))

Answer (score 0):

You could build the masks separately and then pass them in when setting the values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[99, 35, 60, 99, 51], 'b':[0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.04, 0.02], 'c':[5, 6, 3, 0, 1]})
df['nc1'] = np.nan
df['nc2'] = np.nan

a_mask1 = df['a'] > 50
b_mask1 = df['b'] >= 0.04
c_mask1 = df['c'] == 0

a_mask2 = df['a'] >= 50
b_mask2 = df['b'] < 0.04
c_mask2 = df['c'] > 0

mask1 = a_mask1 & b_mask1 & c_mask1
mask2 = a_mask2 & b_mask2 & c_mask2

# set the values for nc1
df['nc1'][mask1] = 'message1'
df['nc1'][mask2] = 'message3'
# set the values for nc2
df['nc2'][mask1] = 'message2'
df['nc2'][mask2] = 'message4'

df
```

In response to your comment about having a long list of conditoins, perhaps this will solve your problem?

```
import operator

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[99, 35, 60, 99, 51], 'b':[0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.04, 0.02], 'c':[5, 6, 3, 0, 1]})

source_col_names = df.columns 

n_new_cols = 3
new_col_names = [f'nc{x+1}' for x in range(n_new_cols)]
df[new_col_names] = np.nan

operators = {
    '<': operator.lt,
    '<=': operator.le,
    '==': operator.eq,
    '>=': operator.ge,
    '>': operator.gt,
}

conditions = [
    {
        'a': {'operator':'>','threshold':50},
        'b': {'operator':'>=','threshold':0.04},
        'c': {'operator':'==','threshold':0},
        'messages': ['message1', 'message2', 'rtyu'], # one for every new column added
    },
    {
        'a': {'operator':'>=','threshold':50},
        'b': {'operator':'<','threshold':0.04},
        'c': {'operator':'>','threshold':0},
        'messages': ['message3', 'message4', '231234'], # one for every new column added
    },
    {
        'a': {'operator':'==','threshold':60},
        'messages': ['xyz', 'rghyt', 'r642'], # one for every new column added
    },
]

for condition in conditions:
    composite_mask = pd.Series(True, index=df.index)
    for new_col_num, new_col_name in enumerate(new_col_names):
        for source_col_name in source_col_names:
            if source_col_name in condition.keys():
                op_str = condition[source_col_name]['operator']
                threshold = condition[source_col_name]['threshold']
                
                op_func = operators[op_str]
                mask = op_func(df[source_col_name], threshold)
                
                composite_mask = composite_mask & mask
        df[new_col_name][composite_mask] = condition['messages'][new_col_num]
        
df
```

There may be more efficient / pythonic ways of performing the loops, but this seems to work as a brute force approach.

This assumes that you would, at some point, need to write your conditions out anyway, so you could just write them into the `conditions` dictionary as a new entry.

You can also provide an arbitrary number of new columns, and give each a condition a message to apply to each new column, as determined by the `messages` list within each entry of `conditions`.

This should work for an arbitrary number of source data columns, and you don't need to provide a condition for every source data column. Of course, by nature of the loops, large numbers of source columns and result columns will be somewhat slow.

Comment: I have a long list of conditions and adding each one like this may not really be a good way of doing it. Any other easier and simpler way to achieve the results?

Comment: @Passive_coder I edited my answer to address that. I assume that you need to write out the conditions at some point anyway, but doing it in a dictionary like this can make it convenient to process the conditions.